Openai whisper failed to load audio or no such file or directory?
I wanted to try out whisper but all Im getting is errors. At first it was something like win 2 error: no such file or directory, then somehow the next day that error dissapeared and I got a new error that was so long it barely fit on screen. When I copied it to chatgpt it propossed these solutions:
-File path issue - But I typed the file adress in correctly
-Permissions:ensure that the program has the necessary permissions to read the file-Im using VSCode
-FFmpeg configuration: The error message also includes information about the FFmpeg version being used. It's possible that there's an issue with the FFmpeg configuration or installation. You might need to reinstall or update FFmpeg to resolve any compatibility issues.
-dependencies: Check if all dependencies required by FFmpeg are installed and properly configured
Im somewhat new to programming and have no idea what a lot of these errors mean.
When I was searching for solutions a lot of people said I should install ffmpeg and I did. Then I set a new path for the ffmpeg.exe file. It still didn't work. I have the audio file in the same folder as the program.
I don't know what to do.
Please help...
This is the program:
import whisper
model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe("Hello.mp3", fp16=False)
with open("transcription.txt", "w") as file:
file.write(result["text"])
....................................................................
This was the error message:
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[in#0 @ 000001528eeb1bc0] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file Hello.mp3.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-nostdin', '-threads', '0', '-i', 'Hello.mp3', '-f', 's16le', '-ac', '1', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '16000', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 4294967294.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "C:\Python_openai_testing\openaiwhisper_test1.py", line 4, in 
result = model.transcribe("Hello.mp3", fp16=False)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[in#0 @ 000001528eeb1bc0] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file Hello.mp3.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory

You have posted the code you are trying to use, thank you. however, in order to help you need to post the exact text of any error messages you are seeing. You may also like to read How do I ask a good question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
